Check a box in Google sheets if all other boxes are checked
I would like to use a formula in conditional formatting where a check box in cell A3 will be checked if all the check boxes in cells C4:C13 are checked.  what formula would I use or is there a different route to take with this.
I am at a loss as I never tried this before with check boxes
I have tried this formula  in A3
=countif(C4:C13, true) = COLUMNS(C4:C13)
how ever it only checks the box in A3 when one if the boxes in C4:C13 is check if more then one is checked it unchecks A3

Your formula should have been =countif(C4:C13, true) = ROWS(C4:C13) but @JamesR's formula is a lot shorter of course

In cell A3, add the formula =AND({C4:C13}), and then select cell A3 and select the menu item Insert > Checkbox to format A3 as a checkbox. The formula evaluates to "C4 AND C5 AND C6 ... AND C13", so it will evaluate to true when all checkboxes in C4:C13 are true (i.e. checked), and false otherwise.
The state of the checkbox will be determined by the underlying formula, so it cannot toggled by clicking.
Conditional Formatting is not appropriate for this task, because it can only change the formatting of a cell (colors and styles), not the value (checked / unchecked).

Nice explanations!

I like it. Not sure if the curly brackets are necessary though - as far as I know And can just take a range like sum, product etc.
